# phonegap app-id one for android and another for ios

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Can I have 2 id's in the same config.xml file on the widget element?
I need this because I had 2 change apple app-id, and because of that, I had to create a new google play app id!
I mean something like this **(id:android AND id:ios)**:

```
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id:android          = "com.phonegap.example"
    id:ios          = "com.phonegap.example"
    versionCode = "10"
    version     = "1.0.0" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
android-packageName     = "com.phonegap.example" 
ios-CFBundleIdentifier  = "com.phonegap.example"
```

instead of

```
id:android      = "com.phonegap.example"
id:ios          = "com.phonegap.example"
```

Comment: Thanks for help.
I created a new ID for both ios and android with the same name, So I don't need this anymore :)